# Library load error on Qt

Tags: qt

I am seeing this error while starting the application on OSX

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtDeclarative.framework/Versions/4/QtDeclarative
  Referenced from: /test/TestApp
  Reason: Incompatible library version: TestApp requires version 4.8.0 or later, but QtDeclarative provides version 4.7.0
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

In projects, I have selected the build configuration as Qt 4.8.0 and Qt version as Qt 4.8.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your QtDeclarative (Qt Quick) libraries seem not to be up-to-date. Use the SDK maintenance tool (usually found in the root directory of your Qt installation) to install the 4.8.0 version of the libraries.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for giving me an insight. Clean command in Qt creator didn't clean the old binaries that I created using Qt 4.7.4 and hence while building with 4.8 it mixed up 4.8 and 4.7 libraries. This made the application to complain.